# How can I send faulted messages to a specific exchange using MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

How could I send a faulted message to a specific exchange (DLX) other than the default provided by MassTransit? I have configured my ReceiveEndpoint as follows but faulted message always end up on the _error queue:

```
                endpoint.SetQueueArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "xxx-sync-exchange.dead");
                endpoint.SetQueueArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "xxx.sync.on-customer-updated-event.dead");
                endpoint.DeadLetterExchange = "xxx-sync-exchange.dead";
```

I appreciate any help provided, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'd likely have to reconfigure the receive pipeline to NACK the message, instead of the default behavior that moves the message to the **_error** queue. You would lose the benefits of the additional exception headers added by MassTransit that include the fault details.

This *might* work, I haven't tried it.

```
endpoint.RethrowFaultedMessages();
```

> You still need to specify the DeadLetterExchange

Comment: I think it didn't work as expected. When an exception is thrown inside a consumer, it then enters in an infinite loop

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if RabbitMQ is setup to handle that, since it uses requeue with the NACK. So, yeah, not possible for NACK'd messages. I've only used the DLE for expired TTL messages.